# Jayatana for Android Studio on 17.04 not working

Tags: unity, java, android-studio, 17.04, intellij

Jayatana worked fine for me on Ubuntu 16.10, but after upgrading to 17.04 the menu of Android Studio doesn't merge with the Ubuntu title bar Anymore.

When starting Android Studio via terminal there are also no messages about jayatana.

I have jayatana installed (obviously) and the: 
`-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar` line added to:

- ./android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions
- ./.AndroidStudio2.3/studio64.vmoptions

**Is this a bug in Ubuntu 17.04 or am I missing something here? Anyone else having troubles making this work?**

Comment: The same behavior in Netbeans IDE 8.2.

Comment: @jsartti yep, just found out that this issue exists in Netbeans too. I tried adding "env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" to the "Exec"-line of the launcher file, but without any result.

Comment: same problem with jayatanaag

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jayatana/+bug/1683800

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Ubuntu 17.04** has a different value for **XDG_CURRENT_DESKTO** env variable

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity:Unity7
```

So changing it back to the following fixes the problem, I don't know other side effects this might have

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
```

Please refer to: [After upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 integrated menus do not work](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-302) for updates.

Comment: It works but unity-control-center only shows some elements and sometimes the Unity Dash is not loaded. We will have to wait for a deeper solution ...

Comment: Thanks, this works! Android Studio has the global menu back. I accepted your answer.

Comment: What about Ubuntu 18.04? I tried with `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`, but it doesn't work 

Answer (score 0):

After trying many options, this reply solved the problem:

[comment link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173836#comment=27-2331466)

[image: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173836#comment=27-2331466]