# Global menu in PhpStorm on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, globalmenu

I'm upgrade my ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04.
Then I deleted manually installed PhpStorm 2017.1.1 and install PhpStorm 2017.1.2 by JetBrains Toolbox

After running PhpStorm, I found that the menu [became standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6BLC.png) (under the title bar).
I don't know if this is the problem with the new PhpStorm or ubuntu.

Ubuntu 16.10 and PhpStorm 2016.1.1 was work fine.

**Question:** How can I get globalmenu in PhpStorm 2017.1.2 on Ubuntu 17.04 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpVkC.png)?

custom phpstorm64.vmoptions from home directory

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dide.no.platform.update=true
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to provide clarity. I for one don't understand what you mean by "menu became standard" Which menu? Perhaps a link to a screenshot would help. Thank you for helping us help you! :-)

Comment: I don't know how to link this question to a similar one that I answered, here's the link to the other question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904911/jayatana-for-android-studio-on-17-04-not-working/906893#906893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same issue here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-302

you should set `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` in the .desktop file after de Exec=

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904911/jayatana-for-android-studio-on-17-04-not-working) is related.